# So it's the first virtual host that will apply when no ServerName is actually matched in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, defaults

This is what I just found by test,

but I don't see any such information on default behavior of apache's virtual host.

Can someone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For this reason, some distributions (Ubuntu is a good example) name the default config file `000-default`.

Comment: Can you provide a reference link?I don't find any document on this yet...

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html "If no matching virtual host is found, then the first listed virtual host that matches the IP address will be used."